# MFC main thread to wait for another thread to end

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to use MFC to create a tool. This tool main job is to sort data. Well, I found that when the tool is sorting, since there is only main thread; therefore, while it is doing sorting work, no dialog boxes can be moved or clicked. Hence, I created another thread to do sorting work and works fine.

But there is another problem after I used a thread. I don't how to make main thread to wait for the sorting thread. I want to do something after sorting thread is done, but right now, main thread just moves onto the next procedures without waiting for sorting thread to finish its work.

Here is snippet

```
AfxBeginThread(processfiles, tVals) // A thread do its work.

// below I want to do something with the result I got from the thread above. 
//But main thread just do its work separately without waiting for the thread to finish its work.
```

.

please help thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

So write code to do that. Pop up a dialog box. Indicate that the sorting is taking place. Do whatever you want. Have the other thread send your thread a signal when it's done, say by sending you a message with `PostMessage`.

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Do you know how to have the thread send a windows message? Do you know how to receive a windows message?

Comment: I want to know how thread to send message to main thread to wait. if you can show me some codes that would be great :)

Comment: Wait for the thread to finish the same way you wait for the user to press 'OK' (which is also a Windows message). Just go on about your business (which probably means returning to your message pump) until you receive the message that the thread completed. (Code the thread to call `PostMessage` when it's done.) Your code will see the completion of the thread as an event like any other event Windows reports to it. [See here](http://www.murrayc.com/learning/windows/multithreading.shtml#Communication)